# Upgraded Postfix and now seeing "discarding EHLO keywords: CHUNKING" in maillog

Tags: centos, rhel, postfix, smtp

Upgraded ***Postfix*** to ***3.5.8-2.el8*** on ***RHEL 8.5*** and started seeing below in `/var/log/maillog`:

```
postfix/smtpd[7575]: discarding EHLO keywords: CHUNKING
```

Reviewed ***main.cf*** and ***master.cf*** but can't see any directive controlling this behaviour. However `postconf | grep chunking` reports:

```
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = chunking
```

***?!?!?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RH compiled this change in the upgraded ***Postfix*** version, so unless you expressly override the behaviour in ***main.cf*** in following way, [then ***chunking*** is disabled out of the box on RH](https://www.mail-archive.com/postfix-users@postfix.org/msg91470.html).

Had to Google and sift through various docs to derive the answer to this, which is:

Append following line to ***/etc/postfix/main.cf***:

```
 smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = ''
```

Reload ***Postfix*** config:

```
 systemctl reload postfix.service
```

Validate ***chunking*** no longer disabled:

```
 postconf | grep chunking
```

Should return no results.

**HOWEVER**: Be aware there is a [use-case for disabling ***chunking***](http://www.postfix.org/BDAT_README.html#downsides)